# Writing content inside a file in R language

Tags: r, file, dataframe, matrix

I am doing a "Noughts and Crosses" in **R** game for class and I have a problem.
I have to write the names of the two players in a file, which I have already created, but it gives me error because I must have mistaken something or have a order mistake regarding the functions "write.table", the data.frame I created for the names…
I upload the code:

```
   write.table(names,"C://progra//players.txt", append=TRUE)
 checknames(names)
 names=data.frame(names=c(player1, player2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 print(names)
 names=checknames(names)
}

checknames<-function(names)
{
 print(names)
 file.exists(players)
 B=read.table("C://progra//players.txt")
 player1=readline(prompt="Player 1, what's your name?: ")
 for(i in 1:nrow(B))
 {
   if(player1==B[i,1])
```

Any suggestion Will be welcomed!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why the python tag? Removed.

Comment: What's the error message and which command triggers it?